# Reload sshd configuration in container without restarting the container

Tags: kubernetes, sshd

I would like to deploy an ssh bastion jumper as a deployment in a Kubernetes cluster. This should receive its sshd_config as well as the authorized_keys via a ConfigMap or Secret. These can of course change over time, so that a reload of the sshd service becomes necessary.

How can I automate this process? Existing ssh connections should not be killed when updating the config or authorized_keys file.

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-server

EXPOSE 22/tcp
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e"]
```

My deployment looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sshd-server
  namespace: sshd
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sshd-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-sshd-server
        image: my-sshd-server-image:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 22
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
          name: sshd_config
        - mountPath: /user/.ssh/authorized_keys
          name: authorized_keys
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mount a `ConfigMap` as a directory, the directory contents will update when you update the `ConfigMap` (possibly after a short delay).

That means if you were just concerned about your `authorized_keys` file, you could do something like this:

Create the following `ConfigMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ssh-config
data:
  authorized_keys: |
    ssh-rsa ...
    ssh-rsa ...
  sshd_config: |
    StrictModes no
    AuthorizedKeysFile  /config/authorized_keys
```

And deploy your ssh pod using something like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sshtest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: quay.io/larsks/alpine-sshd:5
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: sshtest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 22
              name: ssh
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssh-config
              mountPath: /config
            - name: ssh-config
              mountPath: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
              subPath: sshd_config
            - name: ssh-data
              mountPath: /etc/ssh

      volumes:
        - name: ssh-config
          configMap:
            name: ssh-config
            defaultMode: 0440
        - name: ssh-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Where `quay.io/larsks/alpine-sshd:5` is simply alpine + sshd + an
`ENTRYPOINT` that runs `ssh-keygen -A`. You should build your own
rather than random some random person's image :).

This will work on straight Kubernetes but will *not* run on OpenShift
without additional work.

With this configuration (and an appropriate `Service`) you can ssh
into the container *as root* using the private key that corresponds to
one of the public keys contained in the `authorized_keys` part of the
`ssh-config` `ConfigMap`.

When you update the `ConfigMap`, the container will eventually see the
updated values, no restarts required.

---

If you really want to respond to changes in `sshd_config`, that
becomes a little more complicated. `sshd` itself doesn't have any
built-in facility for responding to changes in the configuration file,
so you'll need to add a sidecar container that watches for config file
updates and then sends the appropriate signal (`SIGHUP`) to `sshd`.
Something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sshtest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      shareProcessNamespace: true
      containers:
        - image: docker.io/alpine:latest
          name: reloader
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssh-config
              mountPath: /config
            - name: ssh-data
              mountPath: /etc/ssh
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              while true; do
                if [ -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config ] && [ -f /etc/ssh/sshd.pid ]; then
                  if ! diff -q /config/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then
                    cp /config/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
                    kill -HUP $(cat /etc/ssh/sshd.pid)
                  fi
                fi

                sleep 10
              done
        - image: quay.io/larsks/alpine-sshd:6
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: sshd
          ports:
            - containerPort: 22
              name: ssh
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssh-config
              mountPath: /config
            - name: ssh-data
              mountPath: /etc/ssh
      volumes:
        - name: ssh-config
          configMap:
            name: ssh-config
            defaultMode: 0600
        - name: ssh-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

This requires a slightly modified container image that includes the
following `ENTRYPOINT` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /config/sshd_config ]; then
    cp /config/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
fi

ssh-keygen -A
exec "$@"
```

With this configuration, the `reloader` container watches for changes in the configuration file supplied by the `ConfigMap`. When it detects a change, it copies the updated file to the correct location and then sends a `SIGHUP` to `sshd`, which reloads its configuration.

This does not interrupt existing ssh connections.

Comment: You can find all the files I used while testing this in https://github.com/larsks/so-example-72059674/